# Why are all Lodash functions unavailable on my project? ("not a function" Error)

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, lodash

I just installed lodash and tried to use its `_.lowerCase` function. It did not work as I got *“TypeError: `_.lowerCase` is not a function”*. I reinstalled lodash and tried again with no result. I tried the `_.kebabCase` function as well and it did not work either (got the same error). I read some older posts and did not find a clear solution. Does anybody know what’s the matter with this error?

Here is the part where the error is pointing at (`_.kebabCase` line):

```
app.get("/posts/:content", function(req, res){ 
  let postName = _.kebabCase(req.params.content);
  var checker = false;

  for(let i = 0; i < postArray.length; i++){
    let currentTitle = _.kebabCase(postArray[i].title);

    if(currentTitle == postName){
      checker = true;
      break;
    }
  }
```

Here is the Error message I get:

[image: TypeError: _.kebabCase is not a function]

Comment: How exactly are you including lodash? What is `_` when you log it?

Comment: Are you importing/requiring it into the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are not including/importing `_` in your file.

Add `var _ = require("lodash")`  on top of the file.

Comment: Then where does the existing `_` come from? Looks more like it’s being overwritten.

Comment: Yes it was overwritten. I copied the code from lodash website and I now noticed that I copied two "_". now I replaced it with single require("lodash") and it seems to work fine. Thank you.